# Script for creating a new project in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, project-template

I want to write a template that creates new projects in RStudio. What I want to do is:

1. Create a new Rstudio project in a folder called "MyNewProject"
2. Create a new project using `ProjectTemplate` package in this folder by: `create.project('MyNewProject')`.
3. Make some modifications in this folder.

I believe I can code steps 2 and 3. But I don't know how to create a new project in RStudio by a script. If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `devtools`, particularly the `create` function? (Note that that will create an *R package* in the folder, not just the R project)

Comment: @DavidRobinson No, I did not. I simply want a code that creates a folder that includes "MyNewProject.Rproj" file and a git in that folder to accompany that in Step 1.

Comment: You could write one and put it in your `.Rprofile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing special about a `.Rproj` file, just a text file with (or what ever defaults):

```
Version: 1.0

RestoreWorkspace: Default
SaveWorkspace: Default
AlwaysSaveHistory: Default

EnableCodeIndexing: Yes
UseSpacesForTab: Yes
NumSpacesForTab: 4
Encoding: UTF-8

RnwWeave: knitr
LaTeX: pdfLaTeX
```

So this function would do what you're after:

```
myProject <- function(proj, ...) {

    require(ProjectTemplate)
    create.project(proj, ...)

    x <- c("Version: 1.0", "", "RestoreWorkspace: Default", "SaveWorkspace: Default", 
        "AlwaysSaveHistory: Default", "", "EnableCodeIndexing: Yes", 
        "UseSpacesForTab: Yes", "NumSpacesForTab: 4", "Encoding: UTF-8", 
        "", "RnwWeave: knitr", "LaTeX: pdfLaTeX")

    cat(paste(x, collapse="\n"), file=file.path(proj, paste0(basename(proj), ".Rproj")))

    message(paste(basename(proj), "has been created"))
}

myProject("MyNewProject.Rproj")
```

For the `git` requirement, open the folder and use:

```
qdapTools::repo2github()
```

in the console (of course you'll need to install `qdapTools`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I believe there is no method to create a new project from RStudio's interface by R code. That's fine. I can manage to create a project template using the methods you offered.

Answer (score 8):

With the new package `usethis`, the simpler answer to your question 1 reads:

```
library(usethis)
create_project(path = "MyNewProject", open = TRUE, rstudio = TRUE)
```

This code makes a folder "MyNewProject", creates "MyNewProject.Rproj" file and opens a new RStudio session with working directory "MyNewProject".

In the new session, now in "MyNewProject" folder, you can run the following code to initialize a local git repo

```
library(usethis)
use_git()
```

You can even create a remote repo in github, if you have all git configured properly, with

```
use_github()
```

Two useful references are:

1. [usethis](https://usethis.r-lib.org/articles/articles/usethis-setup.html)
2. [Happy Git and Github for the UseR](https://happygitwithr.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Was looking for this very thing, and noticed that RStudio has recently put out something for this.

Thought I'd put out an answer in case it helps anyone else.

https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of an older question, but for others out there, there is a way to code the .Rproj in a script.

If you look at the `devtools::create` function, there is a function called `use_rstudio`. Looking at the contents of that function you get:

```
> devtools::use_rstudio
function (pkg = ".") 
{
    pkg <- as.package(pkg)
    path <- file.path(pkg$path, paste0(pkg$package, ".Rproj"))
    if (file.exists(path)) {
        stop(pkg$package, ".Rproj already exists", call. = FALSE)
    }
    message("Adding RStudio project file to ", pkg$package)
    template_path <- system.file("templates/template.Rproj", 
        package = "devtools")
    file.copy(template_path, path)
    add_git_ignore(pkg, c(".Rproj.user", ".Rhistory", ".RData"))
    add_build_ignore(pkg, c("^.*\\.Rproj$", "^\\.Rproj\\.user$"), 
        escape = FALSE)
    invisible(TRUE)
}
<environment: namespace:devtools>
```

See the section for `template_path`? That is the code you can use to create the `.Rproj` file. So the end code in the script would be:

```
path <- file.path('path/to/folder', paste0('foldername', ".Rproj"))
template_path <- system.file("templates/template.Rproj", 
    package = "devtools")
file.copy(template_path, path)
```

You can now create an `.Rproj` from code! :)

Comment: I have been using you script using system.file for some times now but it does not work anymore. No idea on what is going wrong ?

Comment: @marc Function `use_rstudio` is now part of the package `usethis` that was uncoupled from `devtools` package in release 2.0.0 oct 30, 2018 [devtool 2.0.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/10/devtools-2-0-0/). See [usethis](https://usethis.r-lib.org/articles/articles/usethis-setup.html).